# Bamboo, NAnt, and PSExec shows no Console UI

Tags: console, nant, bamboo, psexec

I need NAnt to kick off a long running console app on the local machine during a Bamboo build.  It does this correctly but without the console UI.  Rather than try to show all that, I have worked it down to a trivial example that also does not show the UI.

When I type the following:

```
C:\PSExecPath\psexec -d -i ping localhost
```

or

```
C:\PSExecPath\psexec \\localmachinename -d -i ping localhost
```

I get exactly the results one would expect including the UI.

But when this same command is kicked off from NAnt there is no UI.  For example when the following build file is run by NAnt after being started with Bamboo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="all">
    <target name="all">
        <exec program="C:\PSExecPath\psexec.exe" spawn="true">
            <arg value="\\localmachinename" />
            <arg value="-d" />
            <arg value="-i" />
            <arg value="ping" />
            <arg value="localhost" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Just to make sure it is stated, NAnt is being executed in the same profile.

Comment: Trying to add the specific session after the -i (in my case '4') does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo was running as a Service.  I changed it to run as a Console and everything started running as expected.